# Logitech Momo Racing: wheel and pedals move mouse

Tags: mouse, steam, logitech

I've done some research on Google about this subject. I've tried the only fix I found, which was to install pyLinuxWheel. I did it didn't fix my issue.

I start Ubuntu Gamepack v20.04. I plug my Logitech Momo Racing and when I press the accelerator, my mouse move up and down. The steering wheel moves my mouse left to right. And I am unable to use my physical mouse anymore.

I'm a big fan of ETS and ATS on Steam, this is the main reason why I installed Linux on my computer aside Windows 10, since I read it is faster.

Does anybody have any clues or solutions to this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had the same issue on antix(debian 10 based) with a joystick from Greenasia, though my mouse was still usable. Removing xserver-xorg-input-joystick did the trick

```
sudo apt-get remove xserver-xorg-input-joystick
```